# How can i make the DataTable like this in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, datatable

How can I make the DataTable like this in a flutter.

[image]

Comment: Is the 1st column fixed like above ! Age = 3x2 and Etc  = 3x2

Comment: I didn't understand your question

Comment: I mean is that table has fixed length ?

Comment: yes @NaveenAvidi

Comment: can you post the map/json sketch/design !